# Conforming cornerRadius of a subviews inside a UIView

Tags: swift

I have a table view cell which consists of an imageView and a couple of labels. The image is confined to the top of the cell. In order to create the shadow effect, I have a background UIView which acts as the container for the image and labels. I have applied a cornerRadius of 6 to the background view.

You will notice that the bottom of the card has a corner radius applied but the image does not allow this for the top corners.

Here is my background UIView:

```
lazy var restaurantBackground : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }()
```

How can I solve this? maskToBounds or clipToBounds for the background view does not work. It removes the shadow effect.

*Addendum*

```
// Adding the background view
        contentView.addSubview(restaurantBackground)
        restaurantBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        restaurantBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        restaurantBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        restaurantBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        restaurantBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        
        // Adding shadow
        restaurantBackground.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        restaurantBackground.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        restaurantBackground.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        restaurantBackground.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        restaurantBackground.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        restaurantBackground.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        
        // Adding restaurant image to background
        restaurantBackground.addSubview(restaurantImage)
        restaurantImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        restaurantImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: restaurantBackground.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        restaurantImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: restaurantBackground.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        restaurantImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: restaurantBackground.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        restaurantImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: restaurantImage.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0/2.0).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: It is the image view whose top corners must be rounded. However you rounded the bottom corners, that is how you round the top corners.

Comment: You're right. I just need to round the top corners and not the bottom corners.

Comment: Fine, so do that. That's what the `maskedCorners` property is for, or you can make your own mask out of a UIBezierPath.

Comment: I used maskedCorners. Just found out about it thanks to you. Feel free to answer the question and I can choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your food image view needs to be a subview of the resturantBackground view with a border radius, otherwise its normal borders will be placed above the rounded background. Right now, I assume you're adding both views to the same superview.

Comment: The restaurant image is already a sub view of the background view. I added my code to the question. I cannot add a radius to the image because then the bottom of the image could also have corners which would not correspond with the design requirements.